# Free GUI builder to make Jgoodies Forms

Tags: java, forms, swing, jgoodies

I want to make a big form with Jgoodies FormLayout. I have learn recently how to make forms without a GUI builder, but this form is so big that everytime i have to make a change it takes me a while. So i was wondering if there is a free GUI builder for Eclipse and how can i add it?

Comment: *"...but this form is so big that everytime i have to make a change it takes me a while*" Divide and conquer principle never gets old. If your frame is so complex then it's possible to split it into several panels in a cohesive way, most likely. Isn't it? [Nested Layout Approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/how-to-add-jtable-in-jpanel/5630271#5630271) is perfectly applicable even with third party layout managers.

Comment: I have no experience with [Eclipse Windowbuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/), but it's what you asked for. Just Google "eclipse gui buillder" and see more.